# How can i check if there is any content in them main page of joomla?

Tags: php, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

i am using joomla 3 for a web site, i don't use any content in the **main page** but the system output is on because i need to output contents on other pages of the site. the problem is i have a space in the middle of the page where normally the content comes. i know where this comes from but i have to disable it if there is no content on that selected page. i tried to check the

```
$this['template']->render('content')
```

which is actually used to render the specific content. but i was not able to use it in a conditional if. so i need to check if the loaded page has a content output. has anybody a idea how i could do that?

*PS: i dont want do this with css.*

Comment: This code is inside the template file? Or is it on a component?

Comment: it is in the template file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may check if you are showing the main page and render conditionally:

```
<?php
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();
if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault()) {
        $this['template']->render('content');
}
?>
```

For multilingual site check this link for detecting if you are on the default page:
http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_determine_if_the_user_is_viewing_the_front_page

Just curious... why don't use the `<jdoc:type="component/>`?

Comment: Thats it. Thank you Pep for helping (giving the idea) me out ;)